# Module HMRClient not a registered callable module (iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native

After updating to React Native 0.51 I get this error on startup:

```
Module HMRClient not a registered callable module (calling enable)
```

Error comes from **MessageQueue.js**

There does not seem to be a known solution around - at least not for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

[Expo users]

There is a hidden .expo folder in the project directory containing the expo setting

Delete it.

```
ls -la  // to view all folders on mac
```

Comment: I'm not using expo.. Anything else it could be?

Comment: i'm an expo user. And there's any .expo folder in my project folder

Comment: i am an expo user and it worked for me. removing the '.expo' folder fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using windows machine, may be this could help you.

In my case, `adb` path was not set in the `PATH` variable. So I was getting the same error. So set path of **sdk/platform-tools** in your PATH environment variable.